# How to solve the following problem - A ∩ B ⊂ A ⊂ A ∪ B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $$(A \cap B) \subset  A \subset  (A \cup B).$$

I understand $\cap$, $\subset $, $\cup$ concepts, but i wonder how to solve this problem.

Comment: First of all. Suppose that $x \in A\cap B$. Then is it true that $x \in A$? Also for $x \in A$.

Comment: I'm sure you intuitively understand what $\cap, \subset, \cup$ are, but how are you with using them in proofs?

Comment: This should be standard. If $x \in A \cap B$, then by definition $x \in A$. That gives the first inclusion. The second inclusion follows that the union is defined as objects which are in either $A$ or $B$ (or nothing) so if an object is in A then it has to be in the Union

Comment: New bug on the website ? Why after editing, my name is over the OP's name and not next to it ?

Comment: @idm It's fine from my perspective. Still a bug though. Maybe post [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live?cb=1)?

Comment: @TheoBendit : I have the new version of chrome on mac, you too ? (lots of problems these last days with Chrome...)

Comment: @idm I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @TheoBendit: I made a post [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/new-bug-on-the-website).  :)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Theo Bendit, actually, instead, i was just considering the sets of elements of A and B, that would be all elements of belongs to A. But i didn't find a right way to prove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$x\in A\cap B\implies  x\in A\implies  x\in A\cup B.$$
what else ?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain ! How can it be downvoted since it exactly answer to the question ?

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I do have my own criticism of this answer. What you've done is parsed the $\subset$ signs in terms of inequalities, but you haven't parsed the $\cap$ and the $\cup$. To be a full answer (not a hint), you'd need to make the connections between $\cap$ and "and", and $\cup$ and "or" more clear. The OP claims they understand the symbols, but it seems that they struggle with structuring an actual proof, so more than just a symbolic shorthand is probably called for here.